# Mosaic-Style Image Gallery (CSS) from array.map() in React

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, css-grid

Question on styling and layout:

Is there a way to create a mosaic-style grid layout with CSS from an array of images that are being mapped through in the render function of a Component? I'm attempting to create a mosaic-style grid with NextJS, but a pure React solution is welcome and appreciated. Either one will save me!

My render function (or, at least, the section pertinent to this post) looks kind of like this:

```html
return (
  {
    images.map(image => <img ... />)
  }
)
```